# Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Int32' and 'Object'

Tags: asp.net

I'm really stuck at this point where it keeps showing this error.

> Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Int32' and 'Object'.

Here's my code for the `LinqDataSource`

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="dsUser" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="newWAassignemnt.ForumDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
    TableName="Members" Where="Id == @Id1" Select="new (Id, EmailAddress, Name, 
    DateJoined, Last_Login_Date, Position)" OnSelecting="dsUser_Selecting" >
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Id1" QueryStringField="Id" Type="Int32" 
         DefaultValue="NULL" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Please help me.

Comment: <asp:LinqDataSource ID="dsUser" runat="server" ContextTypeName="newWAassignemnt.ForumDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Members" Where="Id == @Id1" Select="new (Id, EmailAddress, Name, DateJoined, Last_Login_Date, Position)" OnSelecting="dsUser_Selecting" >
                <WhereParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Id1" QueryStringField="Id" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="NULL" />
                </WhereParameters>
            </asp:LinqDataSource>

Comment: Is `Id` an int or string? Looks like the `WhereParameters` is looking for `Type="Int32"` but is it actually a string in the database? Maybe change the Type in the `WhereParameters`

Comment: Null is not a valid value for Int32... Try specifying 0 as the default value.